# Quaternion.Euler rotates wrong axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this problem where i have this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2SSI.png)

And then, i tried to rotate the y axis and that the "PartToRotate" follows the "enemy". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVXl7.png)

But then, it rotates the axis z for -90 and i dont know why. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJlmK.png)

Therefore i appreciate if you can help me with this. I leave all the code here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Transform target;
    public float range = 15f;
    public Transform partToRotate;

    public string enemyTag = "Enemy";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("UpdateTarget", 0f, 0.5f);
    }

    void UpdateTarget()
    {
        GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(enemyTag);
        float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        GameObject nearestEnemy = null;

        foreach ( GameObject enemy  in enemies)
        {
            float distanceToEnemy = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);
            if(distanceToEnemy < shortestDistance)
            {
                shortestDistance = distanceToEnemy;
                nearestEnemy = enemy;
            }
        }
        
        if(nearestEnemy != null && shortestDistance <= range)
        {
            target = nearestEnemy.transform;
        }
        else
        {
            target = null;
        }
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (target == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
        Vector3 rotation = lookRotation.eulerAngles;
        partToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation.y, 0f);

    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected ()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range);
    }

}
```

Here are the photos.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA8kt.png). thats how looks before, and the idea with the new code `Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position; float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg; partToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);` 
is that the "partToRotate" follows the enemy (target), and he do that, but it still get (plus the z, that is the axis i want) the x axis.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGHN9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the values for `target.position` and `transform.position` can't ensure it but you may be experiencing a [gimbal lock](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/469/could-someone-please-explain-gimbal-lock).

To avoid gimbal locking you must avoid euler angles and use only quaternions. In your code you create a quaternion, then you get the euler angles and then you create a new quaternion using only the Y axis of those euler angles. I assume that's to restrict the rotation to be on the XZ plane, you can do the same without using euler angles like this:

```
Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(dir.x, 0, dir.z));
partToRotate.rotation = lookRotation;
```

Comment: Hey, i change the code: `Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        partToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);`
Because the idea is that the "partToRotate" follows the enemy transform (target) and this do it pretty well but still rotates the wrong axis. i will edit the post with the photos.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it keeps doing the same.

Comment: @GonzaloUlivi Why did you change the code? Did you even try it before you changed it? To me it looks like this answer will do exactly what you need

Comment: Yes, i try this answer but it still doing the same, as i say above your comment.

Comment: Similarly, I fixed it, since being 2D would be the z that would need to be moved.